# How to translate this statement into propositional logic?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

You are eligible to be President of the USA only if you are at least 35 years old, were born in the USA, or at the time of your birth both of your parents were citizens, and you have lived at least 14 years in the country.

Express your answer in terms of: 
E: “You are eligible to be President of the USA,” 
A: “You are at least 35 years old,” 
B: “You were born in the USA,
P: “At the time of your birth, both of your parents where citizens,”
and R: “You have lived at least 14 years in the USA.”

The sentence seems ambiguous to me?

Comment: Not relevant for the mathematics, but the English sentence does not match the mainstream legal understanding of the Constitution of the USA. The constitution requires presidents to be "natural born citizens", which is usually taken to mean any person who acquired U.S. citizenship **at birth**, no matter how, and a single U.S. citizen parent can, with certain additional conditions, be enough for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Try rewriting it as:

You are eligible to be President of the USA only if:

1. you are at least 35 years old,
2. were born in the USA, or at the time of your birth both of your parents were citizens, and
3. you have lived at least 14 years in the country.

Comment: So would it be E implies conditions or conditions imply E? It's hard to see which way the implication goes?

Comment: Check here for how to read "only if": https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/40879